# Holding down 6 keys during startup. Help program that erases personal data

Tags: snow-leopard, startup

Two months after my update to Snow Leopard, my computer hung. When I restarted I could log in, but then the only thing I could do was moving the mouse cursor. So I called my support. *The support told me to hold 6 keys on the keyboard during startup.* This erased all my personal information but kept all my personal files. What is this program and how does it work? I have not been able to locate any information about it what so ever after a long search. My computer is a MacBookPro 4,1.

Comment: How can something erase all your personal information by keep all your personal files? What do you mean, specifically, by this?

Comment: I'm *guessing* that he was instructed to do a safe boot to bypass startup items—but that doesn't require six keys, nor does it erase information.

Comment: I down voted because I don't have the privilege to vote to close. Unfortunately, your question, as submitted, can't be answered. Your recollection of the event is vague and confusing. If you remember more details, please rewrite the question--we want to help. This wasn't a decision I took lightly. Before down voting I ran your question by a number of fellow consultants, technicians and troubleshooters, both here at AD and through other channels,  and none of us is aware of any secret program to "wipe licenses" (which licenses?) or a six-key-startup modifier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will therefore except the anser I have got. All in all I don't think this question is that important either, mostly I was curious. To bad I can't remember more details, probably since it has gone some time since it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unaware of any six key startup modifiers. The closest is the four key <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to [reset NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379).

Apple documents [Startup key combinations for Intel-based Macs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533).

Comment: It wouldn't. I'm unaware of a key combination that "erases licenses",